# What does this symbol stand for?

Tags: relay, schematics, symbol

Please tell me what this symbol means:

[image: Strange element]

Comment: Is it simple relay or something more specific?

Comment: Given it is rotated 90 deg, I would guess it is some component with a transfer function of a unit step (threshold). Do you have any context to it?

Comment: Thanks for comment. As for context - not much of it. There is few switches, few other relays etc. Basically this element receives 0V or 5V depends on switches states.

Comment: Please post that context even if there is not much of it, it will help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spent 30 minutes looking through all types of the relays and trying to find their symbols.

The device on the ciruit is relay, called *Memory relay*, here's the link to [Wikipedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Symbol_of_memory_relay.JPG). However this page does not have any articles assigned to it, thus I would question the reliability of the information.

Comment: +1 ... also latching relay ... remembers its state through power fails ... A1 and A2 are power supply inputs ... https://www.elkoep.com/memory--latching-relay-mr-42